# Git squash last six commits after requested for PR in upstream

Tags: git, merge, pull-request, git-squash

[image]

I requested  pr#1 from origin/master to upstream. Then I created a new branch ipython_feature while checkout in the master. Before merging pr#1 I requested pr#2 which has some changes with pr#1. Later mt pr#1 has merged successfully. Now I could not squash the last 6 my commits from the ipython_feature branch. 
I couldn't squash all my commits. Any help will be appreciated on how to squash in this scenario?
I used `git rebase -i Head~6` in the ipython_feature branch but returns `fatal: invalid upstream 'Head~6'`.

Comment: how many commits it shows when you git log in iphthon_feature branch? and another thing isn't it would be HEAD not Head?

Comment: It shows 13 commits. And yes that would be the HEAD

Comment: so it was a typo right? I mean here, but you did the command right but still you have the problem, right?

Comment: yes.Anything related to the upstream merge?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     fatal: invalid upstream 'Head~6'
> ```

Note that `HEAD` and `Head` are not the same; hence the error message. It’s also confusing because the word “upstream” is being used in two completely different ways. — If you just want to squash the whole branch, you do not need interactive rebase. Say

```
git checkout ipython_feature
git reset --soft HEAD~6
git commit -m"message"
```